# Flash+Node.JS+Socket.io stuck at handshake authorized

Tags: actionscript-3, node.js, flash, socket.io

I'm writing a small game, socket-based obviously. Everything works fine when in localhost, but when I'm running .swf file from my dedicated server, and trying to connect to node.js server, connection is getting stuck at "handshake authorized":

```
info: Server starting...
   info  - socket.io started
info: Listening on port 4000
info: Server started.
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized _kqPhvoD6jYI-c1Gr7zu
```

And thats it.

- Local SWF File -> Local Node.JS -> works.
- Local SWF File -> Remote Node.JS -> works.
- Remote SWF File -> Remote Node.js -> doesn't work.

Node version 0.10.12. It's not a firewall or antivirus. Tried running on different ports.

Code example:

```
//setup express for serving crossdomain on same port as game
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
app.get("/crossdomain.xml", onGetCrossdomain);
var server=require('http').Server(app);

//setup socket io
var socketIo=require('socket.io');
var io=socketIo.listen(server);

//listen on port
server.listen(currentPort);
console.log("Listening on port "+currentPort);

io.set('transports',
[
 'flashsocket'
]);

io.sockets.on('connection', onConnection);


function onGetCrossdomain(req, res)
{
    res.sendfile(__dirname+'/crossdomain.xml');
}

function onConnection(socket)
{
    console.log("connected");
}
```

Comment: I found that upgrading from node v0.8.x to v0.10.x produced this error. Are you using [simb's Flash Socket.IO](https://github.com/simb/FlashSocket.IO) implementation?

Comment: Should I roll back to 0.8x.x? Or is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: This is something I'm looking into at the moment as well. I posted an [issue](https://github.com/simb/FlashSocket.IO/issues/22) on the github page, but there hasn't been much activity in about a year or so. Rolling back to 0.8.x for your current app may be the best option for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've installed earlier version of node (0.8.25) using n - node version manager (https://npmjs.org/package/n), and everything started working fine. Thanks funseiki!

Comment: I'm also trying to do something similar. Did you ever get it working on node 0.10.x? and if not what exact version of node/socket.io did you go with? thanks.